# Dynamic number of columns bound to a UWP datagrid (Windows Community Toolkit)

Tags: mvvm, datagridview, uwp

Has anyone a sample project with a dynamic number of columns bound to a datagrid in UWP? In WPF I can get it to work with an observable collection of dynamic objects with Telerik Datagrid. But in UWP Telerik does not support dynamic objects. I have tried with the Windows Community Toolkit datagrid but failed with it too.

Answer (score 1):

> Dynamic number of columns bound to a UWP datagrid (Windows Community Toolkit)

derive from Samed Bejtovic's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730207/how-to-fill-datagrid-with-datatable-content-in-uwp-c-sharp/53757369#53757369). We could make Dynamic number of columns in code behind with **Windows Community Toolkit** `DataGrid`. Before fill the `DataGrid`, we need convert the collection to `DataTable`, for example. The following is that load csv file and insert the data to the `DataTable`.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
bool firstLine = true;

var sr = new StreamReader("Assets\\Archive.csv");
while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
{
    if (firstLine)
    {
        firstLine = false;
        var cols = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        foreach (string col in cols)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col, typeof(string)));
    }
    else
    {
        var data = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        dt.Rows.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Then we call the  `FillDataGrid(dt,MyDataGrid)` that could add the `Columns` into `DataGrid` base on above `DataTable`.

```
public static void FillDataGrid(DataTable table, DataGrid grid)
{
    grid.Columns.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
            Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("[" + i.ToString() + "]") }
        });
    }

    var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        collection.Add(row.ItemArray);
    }

    grid.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        string project = reader.GetString(0);
                                        decimal number = reader.GetDecimal(1);
                                        DataCollection.Add(new DataSummary(project, number));
                                    }
```

Datagrid supports auto generated columns. Set the items source to the collection.
https://www.reddit.com/r/UWP/comments/djzcqj/display_datatable_as_datagrid/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x