# How to fill datagrid with datatable in uwp and make the grid editable?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid, expandoobject

Need to populate a Datagrid in UWP with a Datatable.
I could display the contents by following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767049/12053338

However, I am unable to edit the datagrid.

How do I make the Datagrid editable? (tired setting IsReadOnly to false).

Thanks

XAML

```xml
         <controls:DataGrid
                        x:Name="grid" 
                        IsReadOnly="False"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        GridLinesVisibility="All">

        </controls:DataGrid>
```

C#

```
            //Datatable
            var table = new DataTable("Students");
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Name", DataType = typeof(string)});
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Id", DataType = typeof(string)});

            //Add a row
            table.Rows.Add("Akinator","1");

          //Conversion of datatable to datagrid itemsource
          for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
                {
                    Header = table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
                    Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("[" + i.ToString() + "]"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged }

                });
            }
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                if (row.ItemArray.Length > 0)
                    collection.Add(row.ItemArray);


            }
            grid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

*Usage of data table cannot be substituted in this particular case.

Comment: The cells are all editable by default in the DataGrid.  Please share the code that you are using or a [mcve] here.

Comment: Since you are trying add the column by yourself, please set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to *False*. I've tried your code, the issue might be related to the binding that you added in the `DataGridTextColumn`.  If not adding the binding, the cell is editable as normal. If adding the binding, the data will show but the cell is not editable anymore. It looks like the `DataGridTextColumn` failed to generate the edit element.

Comment: I'd suggest you convert the DataTable to a list of modes and then use the list as source. Like the second way in the link you shared.

Comment: My Data table will be generated dynamically, the columns wont be the same each time. Apologies if I am missing out something here, I am new to uwp , please help me out.

Comment: I tried to create the column manually and set binding in the code behind. But I changed the source from a `DataTable` to a list of models. The cell could be edited correctly. It seems that the issue is not only related to the binding itself but also related to the Source -`DataTable`. You might raise an issue in the [Community ToolKit Github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to this, Set IsReadonly to false while creating the columns

```
 //Conversion of datatable to datagrid itemsource
      for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
                Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("[" + i.ToString() + "]"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
                IsReadOnly = false //ADD THIS TO MAKE THE DATAGRID EDITABLE

            });
        }
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row.ItemArray.Length > 0)
                collection.Add(row.ItemArray);


        }
        grid.ItemsSource = collection;
```